# SIGSEGV assigning an object to a dynamic 2d matrix

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to simply assign an element typedefined as `Card` from a vector to `mtr[i][j]`, a 2d matrix stored in heap, but the debugger claims a segmentation fault.

I think I tried everything, trying with a static matrix, checking watches for `NULL`, assigning manually every member of the struct.

Just for curiosity, I tried to change the type of the matrix to `int` and `char`. Even so, the assignation (after properly changing the value to assign) doesn't work.

```
int g_rows = 0, g_cols=0;

typedef struct{
    char color;
    int points;
}Segment;

typedef struct{
    Segment h;
    Segment v;
}Card;


Card** loadBoard(char* fileName, Card* cards) {
    short tileRef; short rot;
    short i=0;
    FILE* fp = fopen(fileName,"r"); if(fp == NULL) return NULL;
    if(fscanf(fp, "%hd %hd\n", &g_rows, &g_cols) == 0) {fclose(fp); return NULL;}
    
    Card **mtr = (Card**)malloc(g_rows * sizeof(**mtr)); if(!mtr){printf("Error on first malloc.\n");}
    for(short i = 0; i<g_rows; i++) {
        mtr[i] = (Card*)malloc(g_cols * (sizeof (*mtr)) );
        if(!mtr[i]) printf("error on 2nd malloc.\n");
    }
    i=0;
    while(!feof(fp)){
        for(short j=0;j<g_cols;j++) {
            fscanf(fp, "%d/%d\n", &tileRef, &rot);
            if (tileRef != -1)
                mtr[i][j] = (rot == 0) ? cards[tileRef] : (Card) {.h = cards[tileRef].v, .v = cards[tileRef].h};
            else
                mtr[i][j] = (Card){{.points=-1,.color='\0'},{.points=-1,.color='\0'}};
        }
        fscanf(fp,"\b\n"); i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return mtr;
}
```

I tried to search problems like these but it's too odd that I ended up researching code examples for 2d dynamic allocation.

Maybe I missed something important but I really can't catch it.

FINAL EDIT: I've found out that che compiler I was using (Clang/LLVM from MingW) was the culprit. I tried to set Visual Studio Community as default toolchain in CLion and no problems has occured.

Comment: There are two variables `g_rows` and `g_cols` which hasn't been declared.

Comment: [Why it's bad to use feof() to control a loop](https://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1043284351&answer=1046476070)

Comment: @csawy I always thought it wasn't as safe as a counter. I tried it for the first time after seeing it in college slides. Thank you.

Comment: @anfauglit sorry, fixed to clarify.

Comment: You have some bugs in your `fscanf` calls.  `%d` is the format specifier for an `int`, and `%hd` for `short int`.  You seem to have them backwards.  Your compiler ought to warn you about this if you have warnings turned on (which you should).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be subtle typos in the malloc calls.

1. In the allocation of the matrix,

   ```
   Card **mtr = (Card**)malloc(g_rows * sizeof(**mtr));
   ```

   malloc is allocating space for `g_rows * sizeof(Card)`. But since mtr is being used to store Card pointers, not Cards, we want `g_rows * sizeof(Card*)`.
2. Then in the allocation of each matrix row,

   ```
   mtr[i] = (Card*)malloc(g_cols * (sizeof (*mtr)) );
   ```

   malloc is allocating space for `g_cols * sizeof(Card*)`. But since each matrix row is being used to store Cards, not Card pointers, we want `g_cols * sizeof(Card)`. This error in particular is bad, because sizeof(Card*) is smaller than sizeof(Card), so not enough memory is being allocated.

There is also a potential problem below in the while loop that reads data from the file. The loop iterates so long as the file continues, without checking whether the `i` variable is still in bounds. So if the file is incorrectly formatted, it could cause this code to write off the end of the matrix and segfault.

Comment: I highly recommend using [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) or [Address Sanitizer (ASan)](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html). These tools automatically check for memory-related errors and are invaluable for debugging these sorts of problems.

Comment: There's a common idiom of writing `ptr = malloc(length * sizeof(*ptr))`.  This code seems to be trying to do that, but has got it slightly wrong; if done consistently, the first instance would be `Card **mtr = malloc(g_rows * sizeof(*mtr));` and the second `mtr[i] = malloc(g_cols * sizeof(*mtr[i]));`.

Comment: @PascalGetreuer You're right for the latter part, I already changed the loop control.
In a first instance I initialized the 2d matrix using respectively `sizeof(Card*)` and `sizeof(Card)`, but I later incorrectly changed those using the name of the variable.
However, the corrected code of @NateEldredge still doesn't work. 
I'll try with ASan later.